# Angular-dart: Automatic conversion of Component's @input fields from attributes

Tags: dart, angular-dart

suppose

`<component list-attribute="a b c" bool-attribute></component>`

Whats is the best way of having the component state like this:

```
@Component(...
class Component{
  List<String> listAttribute; // Should automatically contain [a,b,c]
  bool boolAttribute; // Should automatically contain true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing un Angular to automatically transform values.

This kind of binding

```
 list-attribute="a b c"
```

will always pass a string.

## Possible solutions

At first the property needs an annotation

```
@Input()List<String> listAttribute;
```

Passing a list explicitely

```
 [list-attribute]="['a', 'b', 'c']"
```

Make a setter that does the conversion

```
List<String> _listAttribute
@Input() set listAttribute(String value) {
  _listAttribute = value?.split(' ');
}
```

with

```
list-attribute="a b c"
```

or

```
[list-attribute]="'a b c'"
```

or a custom pipe to do the splitting
like

```
[list-attribute]="a b c | split"
```